# Have a UITableView extend its footer beyond its height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` at the bottom of the screen that pulls up and then snaps back down. When it is pulled up, though, you can see the view behind it because the tableview's height is finite and less than the size of the screen.

I tried using a large footer, but that affects the snap-back of scrolling the table up.

I also tried setting a fixed height for `heightForFooter` and returning a large view from `viewForFooterInSection`, but that view gets cut off after it reaches the height returned by `heightForFooter`

How can I display fixed content beneath my table without affecting its scrolling?

Comment: Table view has a background which can be set

Comment: So do you just want to cover the view behind it and at the same time keep the sticky scroll effect? If so, you can just set the tableView's background color. However, if your want to do something else, you can dynamically set the footer's size by implementing the UIScrollViewDelegate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a background view to your table view, and then add a subview to that view with the color you need. You can position the subview around table/section headers.

In viewDidScroll, update the y position and height of the subview.